# node_modules has no exported member 'BehaviorSubject'

Tags: rxjs, angular5

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { **BehaviorSubject** } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

private goals = new BehaviorSubject(['The initial goal']);
  goal = this.goals.asObservable();

constructor() { }

}

*I am unable run, as I am getting error as below in tooltip:*
[ts] Module '"c:/Users/Admin/free_project/code/ng5/node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject"' has no exported member 'BehaviorSubject'.

Comment: I got one solution, please tell reason for this modification to get in-depth knowledge aslo : import { BehaviorSubject } from **'rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject'**;

Answer (score 4):

No, you shouldn't access `rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject`.

The rule of thumb for RxJS 6 is:

Creation Functions (such as `of`, `from`, etc.) and Observable types (Observable, Subject, BehaviourSubject) are imported from `rxjs`:

```
import {BehaviourSubject} from "rxjs";
```

Operators (such as `map`, `mergeMap`, etc.) are imported from `rxjs/operators`:

```
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";
```